# How to fix OpenGL stack corruption when exiting

Tags: c++, opengl, memory

I've been following some opengl tutorials in C++ (moving from using java, so I know openGL alright, but memory management, pointers, etc I'm a little slow on) from http://www.opengl-tutorial.org, and I'm currently having problems with an error when exiting my application. 
I am trying to add a normals vertex attrib array. It seems to work fine during runtime, but when I exit the application, I get this:

> "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'normalbuffer' was corrupted."

I of course did some googling, and found that this error was normally related to arrays and index out of bounds errors, but `normalbuffer` is just a `GLuint`. As far as I can tell, the code for implementing my `normalbuffer` is identical to that implementing my vertex positions and my uv texture map.

Here is my initialization code:

```
// Create Vertex Buffer
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Create UV Buffer
GLuint uvbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Create Normals Buffer
GLuint normalbuffer;
glGenBuffers(2, &normalbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And then my looped code (run every frame):

```
    //...
    //Load the vertex positions array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
      0, //Specify which attribute index we are using
      3, //Size of the attribute
      GL_FLOAT, //Type of attribute
      GL_FALSE, //Normalized?
      0, //Stride
      (void*)0 //Array Buffer Offset
    );

    //Load the UV positions array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
      1, //Specify which attribute index we are using
      2, //Size of the attribute
      GL_FLOAT, //Type of attribute
      GL_FALSE, //Normalized?
      0, //Stride
          (void*)0 //Array Buffer Offset
    );

    //Load the normal vectors array
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
      glVertexAttribPointer(
      2, //Specify which attribute index we are using
      3, //Size of the attribute
      GL_FLOAT, //Type of attribute
      GL_FALSE, //Normalized?
      0, //Stride
      (void*)0 //Array Buffer Offset
    );

    //glDrawArrays() happens here
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    //...
```

This error doesn't seem to happen at all during run time, only when I close the program by hitting the escape key (so I'm not killing the process in VS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st parameter of [`glGenBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml) specifies the number of buffer object names to be generated.

You generate 2 objects, but pass the address of the single variable `normalbuffer` to `glGenBuffers`.
2 objects are generated and the names of the objects are written to the memory addressed by `&normalbuffer` and `(&normalbuffer) + 1`. This causes the stack corruption.

Change the number of objects to be generated:

`GLuint normalbuffer;`
<s>`glGenBuffers(2, &normalbuffer);`</s>
`glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);`